# CorruptedTransactionLogException : corrupted log found

Tags: spring-boot

when I start spring boot application I got an error something like

> bitronix.tm.journal.CorruptedTransactionLogException: corrupted log found at position 520448 (no record terminator found)
>               at bitronix.tm.journal.TransactionLogCursor.readLog(TransactionLogCursor.java:102)
>               at bitronix.tm.journal.TransactionLogCursor.readLog(TransactionLogCursor.java:67)
>               at bitronix.tm.journal.DiskJournal.collectDanglingRecords(DiskJournal.java:363)
>               at bitronix.tm.journal.DiskJournal.collectDanglingRecords(DiskJournal.java:210)
>               at bitronix.tm.recovery.Recoverer.run(Recoverer.java:128)
>               at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.(BitronixTransactionManager.java:87)
>               at bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager(TransactionManagerServices.java:75)
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.BitronixJtaConfiguration.bitronixTransactionManager(BitronixJtaConfiguration.java:100)
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.BitronixJtaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$819e4b58.CGLIB$bitronixTransactionManager$2()
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.BitronixJtaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$819e4b58$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$88ec44ea.invoke()
>               at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.BitronixJtaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$819e4b58.bitronixTransactionManager()
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)

Any idea what cause i got error and how to resolve?

thank you in advance
thank you in advance

Comment: Could you post the POM of your project? Any specific configuration? This stack seems not enough.

Comment: fixed issue by deleting btm1.log and btm2.log file

Comment: @AkashShah you should answer your question. May help others.